# Use generate_series() with get_raw_page()

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like generate a series of numbers (e.g. from 0 to 50) and use this series as an argument for the get_raw_page() function in PostgreSQL.

```
select count(*) as record_count 
from heap_page_items(get_raw_page('test_table', generate_series(0,10)));
```

The problem is that get_raw_page() does not accept tables as argument. How can I use table of numbers as argument for get_raw_page()?

```
ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select (
    select count(*)
    from heap_page_items(get_raw_page('test_table', i))
) as record_count 
from generate_series(0,10) s(i)
```

Or a lateral join if using version 9.3+

```
select count(*) as record_count
from
    generate_series(0,10) s(i)
    left join lateral
    heap_page_items(get_raw_page('test_table', s.i)) on true
```